Can't edit custom tkitner Entry boxes after pressing my 'save' button
After clicking the 'save' button, a message box will appear, shortly after, the placeholders within the entry boxes are deleted. However, upon dismissing the message box, I'm unable to edit the two entry boxes in my application. Any help is greatly appreciated!
I tried changing the state and using focus.set(), however, both did not fix my issue.
The two messageboxes
def submitTask(self):
        title = self.taskTitle.get()
        summary = self.taskSummary.get()
        # checks if summary outputs the placeholder
        if summary == "Task Summary...":
            summary = ""

        # checks if the title is empty or has the placeholder
        if title == "Task Title..." or title == "":
            msg1 = CTkMessagebox(
                title="Message",
                message="Please enter in a Task Title.",
                justify="center",
            )
        

        else:
            msg2 = CTkMessagebox(
                title="Message",
                message=f"Title: {title}\nSummary: {summary}",
                justify="center",
            )

        self.taskTitle.delete(0, "end")
        self.taskSummary.delete(0, "end")

 def createWidgets(self):
        # task title entry box
        self.taskTitle = CTkEntry(
            self,
            placeholder_text="Task Title...",
            width=1000,
            height=65,
            font=(
                "Helvetica",
                35,
            ),
            placeholder_text_color="white",
            text_color="white",
        )
        self.taskTitle.pack(padx=50, pady=(20, 35))

        # task summary entry box
        self.taskSummary = CTkEntry(
            self,
            placeholder_text="Task Summary...",
            width=1000,
            height=65,
            font=("Helvetica", 35),
            placeholder_text_color="white",
            text_color="white",
        )
        self.taskSummary.pack(padx=50, pady=(10, 25))

        # back button
        self.backButton = CTkButton(
            self,
            text="ᐊ BACK",
            fg_color="#ed5e63",
            text_color="black",
            hover_color="#f28c8f",
            border_color="black",
            border_width=2.2,
            corner_radius=16,
            command=self.confirmChanges,
            width=160,
            height=45,
        )
        self.backButton.pack(side="left", anchor="s", padx=(20, 10), pady=30)
        self.backButton.configure(font=("Helvetica", 15))

        # save button
        self.saveButton = CTkButton(
            self,
            text="SAVE",
            fg_color="#ed5e63",
            text_color="black",
            hover_color="#f28c8f",
            border_color="black",
            border_width=2.2,
            corner_radius=16,
            command=self.submitTask,
            width=160,
            height=45,
        )
        self.saveButton.pack(side="right", anchor="s", padx=(10, 20), pady=30)
        self.saveButton.configure(font=("Helvetica", 15))


Cannot reproduce the issue in my Python 3.12.3 in Windows 11 with customtkinter 5.2.2 and CTkMessagebox 2.5.

@Harry Yuan. Your code is working. What is your platform?

@acw1668  import customtkinter as ctk
from CTkMessagebox import CTkMessagebox    app = App()
app.createWidgets()
app.mainloop()
